# Maximum entropy discrete distributions with specified mean

Tags: maximum-entropy, discrete-distributions

Consider a discrete distribution on {1, ...,n}, with mean given as $m$, what is the maximum entropy distribution?

I know it takes the form $p_{X}(k)=ar^{k}$ and is a geometric distribution when n is infinity but is there a way to solve for $r$ and $a$ explicitly in this case?